# Jquery check if clicked, else do this

Tags: jquery

Why does it ignore the click and goes to the else statement? Any help is appreciated!

```
<div id="boxauto"> <a id="boxclose">X</a> error </div>

<script>
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('#boxauto').delay(50).animate({'top':'0'},200); 

        var hasBeenClicked = false;
        jQuery('#boxclose').click(function(){
           hasBeenClicked = true;
        });
        if(hasBeenClicked) {
            $('#boxauto').animate({'top':'-50em'},500);
        } else {
            $('#boxauto').delay(5000).animate({'top':'-50em'},500);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The `if` runs when the timeout occurs, not after the user clicks the button.

Comment: Because you set `hasBeenClicked` to true, bind the click handler, then immediately check the value of `hasBeenClicked`. There's no opportunity for the user to click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the click listener and checking the result at exactly the same time, so both blocks of code are executed immediately.

`hasBeenClicked` will therefore always be false, as there's no way your link could be clicked before the if statement is called.

---

After reading your comments, this is what you need:

```
var hasBeenClicked = false;

// do this as soon as the doc is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

    // move your box into it's intial position
    $('#boxauto').delay(50).animate({'top':'0'},200);

    // listen for the click
    jQuery('#boxclose').click(function() {
        // on click, set the flag and move the box
        hasBeenClicked = true;
        $('#boxauto').animate({'top':'-50em'},500);
    });

});

// after five seconds, move the box if it wasn't moved already
window.setTimeout(function(){
    if (!hasBeenClicked) {
        $('#boxauto').animate({'top':'-50em'},500);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: this doesn't run for me :/

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you'd like the code to do?

Comment: i want a notification box slide down, stay for 5 seconds and close, or close right away when the user clicks x

Comment: @Gadgetster - Updated for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the handler in the timeout. The user never has the chance to click the button. Do this instead:

```
<div id="boxauto"> <a id="boxclose" href="#">X</a> error </div>

<script>
var hasBeenClicked = false;

jQuery('#boxclose').click(function(e){
   hasBeenClicked = true;
   e.preventDefault();
});

window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('#boxauto').delay(50).animate({'top':'0'},200); 

    if(hasBeenClicked) {
        $('#boxauto').animate({'top':'-50em'},500);
    } else {
        $('#boxauto').delay(5000).animate({'top':'-50em'},500);
    }
});
</script>
```

Note, you aren't actually giving a time to the `setTimeout` call. I think the default is something like `400ms`. I doubt the user will be able to click the button that fast.

I also noticed you don't have a reference for your `<a>`. You need to give it an `href='#'` so it knows to not go anywhere. And use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the link from actually navigating.

Comment: This won't work, as you're setting `hasBeenClicked` on the line immediately before the `if` statement, so it will never evaluate to anything other than false.

Comment: @MarkOrmesher Good catch. Updated.

Comment: this slides the notification box but doesn't react to the x click still